# Can't save XML file, cannot access the file '\\Server\Folder\Access.xml' because it is being used by another process

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm new to programing, and have very little experience in Visual Studio.

I'm trying to open an XML file, change a element, then save it.  I've checked Google a few hours now but I haven't found an answer.  I'm just not getting it.  Any help would be appreciated.

My XML doc, at \\Server\Folder\Access.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TDA>
  <Folder>XXXX</Folder>
  <Extended>False</Extended>
</TDA>
```

And here is the code I'm using:

```
    Private Sub btnExtendTo60_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExtendTo60.Click

        ' Get selected item from grid
        Dim LocDir As String = "\\Server\Folder"

        ' Open Access.xml
        Dim myxml As New XmlDocument
        myxml.Load(LocDir & "\Access.xml")

        ' Get XML Node to change
        Dim myxmlnode As XmlNode
        myxmlnode = myxml.SelectSingleNode("/TDA/Extended")

        ' Write to Access.xml Extended tag to "True"
        myxmlnode.ChildNodes(0).InnerText = "True"

        ' Save Access.xml
        myxml.Save(LocDir & "\Access.xml")

    End Sub
```

I'm expecting it to save the file, however, I get the error:

```
The process cannot access the file '\\Server\Folder\Access.xml' 
because it is being used by another process.
```

I don't have the file open.  I can recreate the file without issue.
I've stepped in right before the save, and it looks like the ChildNode has changed to "True", but stepping over to the save line, errors out.

Should I be Disposing or closing the ChildNode somehow before saving?

Answer (score 0):

So, I just ended up saving to a different file, and adding code to rename the update file to the current xml.  Very ugly solution, but it worked.  I ran into another issue that said the xml file was in use when I tried to delete that folder.

After looking around some more, it looks like I didn't close out of my filestream.  I didn't think I needed to since it was just reading the xml file, but I was wrong.

Posting this in case anyone else stumbles here and wanted an answer.